# How to concurrently run nodejs and angular4 with single command?

Tags: node.js, angular

I have angular4 and nodesjs on the server side. How can I combine the scripts in package.json so that the node server and angular start in a single shot?

Comment: use "start" property under "scripts" in package.json. "scripts": { start: node server.js && ng serve }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) and [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

Install these packages using

```
npm i concurrently nodemon
```

Add the following line to **package.json**

```
scripts": {
    "serve": "concurrently \"ng serve\" \"./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js ./node_server/bin/www\"",
}
```

Run the script using

```
npm run serve
```