# Run backend directly in Angular ng serve

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm currently developing using `ng serve`, with proxy configuration, while the proxy points to another nodejs instance on the same machine.

This backend is a simple express server, like this (simplified):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var customers = require('./customers.controller.js');
app.get('/api/customers', customers.getAll)
var server = app.listen(8081)
```

The frontend (`ng serve`) runs on port 4200 and proxies /api to http://localhost:8081/api

As far as I can see, this is the recommended setup.

However, I would prefer to have the backend running directly inside of `ng serve` instance instead of the proxy.
And if possible, even take advantage of the automatic reload feature of ng so that I don't have to restart the server if I change something on the backend code.

As both are nodejs and `ng` seems to be configurable, I think this is possible, but I can't find a starting point for defining my own routes

Comment: You want to run both app on single command?

Comment: @Chellappanவ exactly. both services on the same port 4200

Comment: This link might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47608173/how-to-concurrently-run-nodejs-and-angular4-with-single-command

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to do this
you just need to put your angular into the backend by utilize the nodejs routing

basicly angular is a "static file" and the entry point is coming from the index.html

```
    // Redirect all the other resquests
    this.app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('dist/index.html'));
    });
```

but remember you need to handle the routing for image, js, css and others also.

Comment: This is more how to do it _after_ developing. But I want to keep all the developer benefits of `ng serve`, like auto-compile and auto-reload. I don't want to integrate angular in the backend, i want to integrate the backend in angular.